# When i add go mod to my project, a can't run it, how can i fix it?

Tags: go, go-modules

I wrote an app and when i add go modules to my project `go mod init` and try to start `go run app.go` i had an error: `build command-line-arguments: cannot load github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n: module github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n@latest (v2.0.2+incompatible) found, but does not contain package github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n`. What can i do with this problem?

go.mod:

```
require (
    github.com/BurntSushi/toml v0.3.1
    github.com/blang/semver v3.5.1+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/dyatlov/go-opengraph v0.0.0-20180429202543-816b6608b3c8 // indirect
    github.com/go-ldap/ldap v3.0.3+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/handlers v1.4.2
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.3
    github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server v5.11.1+incompatible
    github.com/pborman/uuid v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/syndtr/goleveldb v1.0.0
    go.uber.org/zap v1.12.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20191029031824-8986dd9e96cf // indirect
    gopkg.in/asn1-ber.v1 v1.0.0-20181015200546-f715ec2f112d // indirect
    gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2 v2.0.0 // indirect
)
```

go.sum:

```
...
github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n v2.0.2+incompatible 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you're importing the correct package. It looks like that package was moved to github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n/v2, so import that instead.

Comment: This package used in other package, i nowhere imported there. I importing package with name ```x```, and package ```x``` use ```github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n/v2```

Comment: If this is imported by another module you import, then this is what I'd try: Add github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n to your require section, and then add replace github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n => github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n/v2, and see if that solves it. I haven't had this exact problem before, but I had similar problems, and this might work.